Solving Einstein vacuum equations related to a specific metric
Let the following metric
$g = \begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2}{3} (\lambda+\mu)} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & e^{\lambda} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r^2 e^{\mu} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & r^2 sin^2 \theta 
\end{pmatrix}$
be defined in spherical coordinates with the functions $\lambda=\lambda(r,\theta)$ and $\mu=\mu(r,\theta)$ to solve the Einstein vacuum equations $R_{ij}=0$ with $i,j$ related to the variables $t,r,\theta,\phi$ (time, radius and two angles). Set into the Einstein equations, the following set of five equations have to be solved:
$[1] \quad R_{tt} = \\
\qquad \frac{e^{\frac{2}{3} (\lambda+\mu)}}{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}} \left( \partial_r \left( \frac{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}}{e^{\lambda}} \partial_r ln \ e^{\frac{1}{3} (\lambda+\mu)}\right) + \partial_\theta \left( \frac{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}}{r^2 e^{\mu}} \partial_\theta ln \ e^{\frac{1}{3} (\lambda+\mu)}\right) \right) \\
\qquad = 0 $
$[2] \quad R_{rr} = \\
\qquad - \frac{e^{\lambda}}{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}} \left( \partial_r \left( \frac{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}}{e^{\lambda}} \partial_r ln \ e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda}\right) + \partial_\theta \left( \frac{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}}{r^2 e^{\mu}} \partial_\theta ln \ e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda}\right) \right) \\
\qquad - \frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{3} (\lambda+\mu)}} \partial_r^2 e^{\frac{1}{3} (\lambda+\mu)} - \frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda}} \partial_r^2 e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda} - \frac{1}{r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu}} \partial_r^2 ( r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu}) - \frac{1}{r \ sin \theta} \partial_r^2 (r \ sin \theta) \\
\qquad   2 \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda}}{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}} \partial_r \left( \frac{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}}{e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda}} \partial_r ln \ e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda}\right) = 0 $
$[3] \quad R_{\theta \theta} = \\
\qquad - \frac{r^2 e^{\mu}}{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}} \left( \partial_r \left( \frac{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}}{e^{\lambda}} \partial_r ln \ (r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu})\right) + \partial_\theta \left( \frac{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}}{r^2 e^{\mu}} \partial_\theta ln \ ( r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu} )\right) \right) \\
\qquad - \frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{3} (\lambda+\mu)}} \partial_\theta^2 e^{\frac{1}{3} (\lambda+\mu)} - \frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda}} \partial_\theta^2 e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda} - \frac{1}{r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu}} \partial_\theta^2 ( r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu}) - \frac{1}{r \ sin \theta} \partial_\theta^2 (r \ sin \theta) \\
\qquad + 2 \frac{r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu}}{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}} \partial_\theta \left( \frac{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}}{r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu}} \partial_\theta ln \ (r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu})\right) = 0 $
$[4] \quad R_{\phi \phi} = \\
\qquad - \frac{r^2 sin^2 \theta}{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}} \left( \partial_r \left( \frac{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}}{e^{\lambda}} \partial_r ln \ (r sin \theta)\right) + \partial_\theta \left( \frac{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}}{r^2 e^{\mu}} \partial_\theta ln \ (r sin \theta) \right) \right) \\
\qquad= 0 $
$[5] \quad R_{r \theta} = R_{\theta r} = \\
\qquad - \frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{3} (\lambda+\mu)}} \partial_r \partial_\theta e^{\frac{1}{3} (\lambda+\mu)} - \frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda}} \partial_r \partial_\theta e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda} - \frac{1}{r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu}} \partial_r \partial_\theta ( r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu}) - \frac{1}{r \ sin \theta} \partial_r \partial_\theta (r \ sin \theta) \\
\qquad + \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda}}{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}} \partial_\theta \left( \frac{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}}{r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu}} \partial_r ln \ (r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu})\right) \\
\qquad + \frac{r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu}}{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}} \partial_r \left( \frac{r^2 sin \theta e^{\frac{5}{6} (\lambda+\mu)}}{r e^{\frac{1}{2} \mu}} \partial_\theta ln \ e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda}\right) = 0 $
It is possible to transform [1] to [5] to [6] to [10]
$[6] \quad R_{tt} = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{3} (-\lambda -\mu)}}{18 r^2} \left(e^{\mu } (4 r^2 \partial_r \lambda \partial_r \mu - r^2 (\partial_r \lambda)^2 + 6 r^2 \partial_r^2 \lambda + 5 r^2  (\partial_r \mu )^2 + 6 r^2 \partial_r^2 \mu + 12 r \partial_r \lambda + 12 r \partial_r \mu ) \\+ e^{\lambda } ( 2 \partial_\theta \lambda \left(2 \partial_\theta \mu + 3 \cot\theta \right) + 5 (\partial_\theta \lambda)^2 + 6 \partial_\theta^2 \lambda - (\partial_\theta \mu )^2 + 6 \partial_\theta^2 \mu + 6 \cot\theta \partial_\theta \mu ) \right) = 0$
$[7] \quad R_{rr} = \frac{e^{-\mu }}{36 r^2} \left(r e^{\mu } \left(\partial_r \lambda \left(7 r \partial_r \mu + 36\right) - 6 r \left(2 \partial_r^2 \lambda + 5 \partial_r^2 \mu \right) + 2 r (\partial_r \lambda)^2 - 13 r (\partial_r \mu)^2 - 36 \partial_r \mu \right) \\
- e^{\lambda } ( 3 \partial_\theta \lambda \left(6 \cot\theta - \partial_\theta \mu \right) + 15 (\partial_\theta \lambda)^2 + 18 \partial_\theta^2 \lambda \right)) = 0$
$[8] \quad R_{\theta \theta} = 
\frac{1}{36} \left(
-3 e^{\mu -\lambda} \left(-r^2 \partial_r \lambda \partial_r \mu + 5 r^2 (\partial_r \mu)^2 + 6 r^2 \partial_r^2 \mu - 2 r \partial_r \lambda + 22 r \partial_r \mu + 12 \right) \\
- 30 \partial_\theta^2 \lambda - 12 \partial_\theta^2 \mu + 36 + 7 \partial_\theta \lambda \partial_\theta \mu - 13 (\partial_\theta \lambda)^2+2 (\partial_\theta \mu)^2+18 \cot\theta \partial_\theta \mu \right) = 0$
$[9] \quad R_{\phi \phi} = \frac{1}{6} \sin^2 \theta e^{-\lambda -\mu } \left( e^{\mu } 
 (r \partial_r \lambda - 5 r \partial_r \mu - 6) + e^{\lambda } (- 5 \cot\theta \partial_\theta \lambda + \cot\theta \partial_\theta \mu + 6 )\right) = 0$
$[10] \quad R_{r \theta} = R_{\theta r} = \\
\frac{1}{18 r}\left(\partial_\theta \mu \left(-2 r \partial_r \lambda + r \partial_r \mu + 6\right) + \partial_\theta \lambda \left(r \partial_r \lambda + 4 r \partial_r \mu + 15\right) - 6 r \left(\partial_r \partial_\theta \lambda + \partial_r \partial_\theta \mu \right) + 9 r \cot\theta \partial_r \mu\right) = 0 $
I am searching for the functions $\lambda$ and $\mu$ solving equations [1] to [5] respectively [6] to [10].
Does anyone have an idea on the best way to approach a solution?
